# Exception has occurred: UnicodeDecodeError 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm doing scraping on this website but when I iterate I find the following message:
Exception has occurred: UnicodeDecodeError
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 614: invalid continuation byte

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

links=['https://www.yapo.cl/vi/74410346.htm?ca=15_s', 'https://www.yapo.cl/vi/73845701.htm?ca=15_s']

for link in links:
    uClient = requests.get(link)
    soup = soup(uClient.content, "html.parser")
    containers = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"price price-final"})
    print(containers)
```

Comment: You are scraping a webpage without checking the status of the response. I ran it and got a status of 403 - forbidden. Consider using uClient.raise_for_status() before loading html into soup. This will throw an error if status code is 400 or 500.

Comment: I already did, but that is not the problem, (I recibed the code 200). :-(  thks for your help anyway

Comment: Sorry my bad, I saw the 403 error and didn't proceed any further. "findAll" should be "find_all". I would recommend print(soup.prettify()) - to find the character that can't be decoded. It maybe you need uClient.text

Comment: now I know that the problem is the "ñ", can't decode it

Comment: Can you check the encoding that you're using by printing uClient.encoding and uClient.apparent_encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get the data for one URL and it worked for me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-charset": "cp1254,ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "accept-language": "tr,tr-TR,en-US,en;q=0.8",
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers
    r = session.get('https://www.yapo.cl/vi/74410346.htm?ca=15_s', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    data = soup.find("div",{"class":"price price-final"})
    response = session.get("https://www.yapo.cl/vi/74410346.htm?ca=15_s".format(data=data))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    print(data.text)
```